# Sending HTTP request with Guzzle failed from Laravel Queue: Getting cURL error 56

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-queue

I'am trying to make an outgoing HTTP request to a distant server using Guzzle library from a laravel queue. I get this error:

```
cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

My code working fine if i made the test locally by running `php artisan queue:work` in my console. But when i made the test on my server, where my laravel queue are managed using supervisor, i always get this error.

Here is the configuration of my supervisor.conf file:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/tef/current/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/worker.log
```

Comment: You may have a proxy blocking access?

Comment: I don’t use any proxy

Comment: Do you provision your server yourself?

Comment: show the relevant script, how do you request using guzzle?